# Parent call child function but fail to initiate component ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get this warning:

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attemps to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Parent:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tElement = React.createRef();
  }

compoenentDidMount() {
    this.tElement .current.loadTx();
}
```

Call child component:

```
 <Tt ref={this.tElement } />
```

The child is a `React.Cmponent` export as react-redux connect:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Tt extends Component {
   loadTx = async () => {
   }
} 

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TransactionHistoryScene);
```

---

**I solve it by using component props and state to refresh the component.**

Comment: Care to show us the child component as well ?

Comment: Seems you're setting `this.tElement.current.loadTx` in constructor so `ref` in DOM is not available yet, try to do it the second one in `componentDidMount` when the child is already mounted.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia, I get null is not an object ..

Comment: Maybe it is a stateless component, so cannot be ref.

Comment: Maybe I will use state and props to change it. thnks

Comment: I believe it's because you are using `connect` from redux. It's a higher order component

Comment: In a stateless component you should use `useEffect` in order to expect the same behaviour as statefull. Just pass an empty array and it will work as `ComponentDidMount`. like this `useEffect(() => {  }, []);`